# Why my code doesn't work to changing attributes on button odoo 15

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-15

i'm using odoo 15, and i want to change attributes button on stock.quant tree view editable. for code like this:

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_apply_inventory']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': ['|', ('inventory_quantity_set', '=', False), ('is_approved', '=', False)]}</attribute>
                <attribute name="groups">base.group_system,pitik_base_farm.group_finance_head</attribute>
                <attribute name="string">Submit</attribute>
            </xpath>
```

But this code doesn't work, not effect on view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtpTk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJFIr.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `is_approved` field in domain of the `invisible` attrs but this field does not exist in the view. You need to add it to the view to be able to use it in the domain.

```
    <record id="view_stock_quant_tree_inventory_editable_inherit_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">stock.quant.inventory.tree.editable.inherit.custom</field>
        <field name="model">stock.quant</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_stock_quant_tree_inventory_editable"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='inventory_quantity_set']" position="after">
                <field name="is_approved" invisible="1"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_apply_inventory']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': ['|', ('inventory_quantity_set', '=', False), ('is_approved', '=',
                    False)]}
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="groups">base.group_system,pitik_base_farm.group_finance_head</attribute>
                <attribute name="string">Submit</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: it same doesn't work

Comment: I have tested it and I confirm its working in Odoo 15